Why I'm not able to erase text on an EditText running within an Handler?
Here's my code I have within an Activity (API Level 30):
EditText loggerText;
final Handler handlerLogger = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
final int delayHandlerLogger = 200; 

public void syncSongs() {
    handlerLogger.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    loggerText.setText("");
    loggerText.post(this::processLogger);
}

public void processLogger() {
    handlerLogger.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (!isQueueEmpty()) {
                String loggerLine = getQueueLastString;
                String textCheck = loggerText.getText().toString();
                loggerText.append(loggerLine + "\n");
            }
            handlerLogger.postDelayed(this, delayHandlerLogger);
        }
    }, delayHandlerLogger);
}

When I call syncSongs() from public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) method (which should erase text with setText("") before post), first time it enters on if (!isQueueEmpty()) { statement, textCheck (i.e. the text from loggerText, which should be empty, due to setText("")) is not "".
Why? Am I missing somethings? What's not correct to deal with it on this async process?
It seems loggerText Is a duplicate object within Runnable, because when I switch Activity and check it onResume/onStart, text is empty, while within Runnable remains the appended text on previous iteration (can't get this).
EDIT - added a new version of code to be checked with users:
public void syncSongs() {
    if (!syncService.isRunning) {
        handlerLogger.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        loggerText.setText("");
        String textCheck1 = loggerText.getText().toString();
        loggerText.post(this::processLogger);
        syncService.syncSongs();
        buttonSyncSongs.setVisible(false);
    }
}

public void processLogger() {
    handlerLogger.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (!isQueueEmpty()) {
                String loggerLine = getQueueLastString;
                String textCheck2 = loggerText.getText().toString();
                loggerText.append(loggerLine + "\n");
            }
            handlerLogger.postDelayed(this, delayHandlerLogger);
        }
    }, delayHandlerLogger);
}

Here the test in Debug I've made (placing two breakpoints, after textCheck1 and textCheck2):

call syncSongs() first time, it firsts stop to textCheck1, which is ""
second stop to textCheck2, which is also empty

Than:

call syncSongs() again; stop at textCheck1, which is "" (correct, I've clean it in the prev instruction)
second stop textCheck2 (which SHOULD BE the same of textCheck1, empty), but it still contains prev values :(

This make no sense...
EDIT 2 - posted whole code:
package com.myapp.test;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.myapp.test.managers.StorageManager;
import com.myapp.test.models.SyncServiceCallbacks;
import com.myapp.test.services.SyncService;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.Objects;

public class SyncActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SyncServiceCallbacks {
    SyncService syncService;
    boolean syncServiceBounded = false;
    final ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            syncServiceBounded = true;
            SyncService.LocalBinder localBinder = (SyncService.LocalBinder) service;
            syncService = localBinder.getServerInstance();
            syncService.setCallbacks(SyncActivity.this);
            syncService.refreshFolderSize();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            syncServiceBounded = false;
            syncService = null;
        }
    };
    final Handler handlerLogger = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    final int delayHandlerLogger = 200;

    ActionBar toolBar;
    MenuItem buttonSyncSongs;
    EditText loggerText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sync);
        toolBar = Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar());
        toolBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        loggerText = findViewById(R.id.loggerText);
        toolBar.setTitle("Sync Songs (Loading...)");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        String textCheck = loggerText.getText().toString();

        Intent syncServiceIntent = new Intent(this, SyncService.class);
        bindService(syncServiceIntent, serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (syncServiceBounded) {
            unbindService(serviceConnection);
            syncServiceBounded = false;
            syncService.unsetCallbacks();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sync_menu, menu);
        buttonSyncSongs = menu.findItem(R.id.btnSyncSongs);
        buttonSyncSongs.setVisible(false);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        if (itemId == android.R.id.home) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SyncActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        } else if (itemId == R.id.btnSyncSongs) {
            try {
                syncSongs();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void syncSongs() {
        if (!syncService.isRunning) {
            handlerLogger.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            loggerText.setText("");
            String textCheck1 = loggerText.getText().toString();
            loggerText.post(this::processLogger);
            syncService.syncSongs();
            buttonSyncSongs.setVisible(false);
        }
    }

    public void processLogger() {
        handlerLogger.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (!syncService.storageManager.logger.isEmpty()) {
                    String loggerLine = syncService.storageManager.logger.dequeue();
                    String textCheck2 = loggerText.getText().toString();
                    loggerText.append(loggerLine + "\n");
                }
                handlerLogger.postDelayed(this, delayHandlerLogger);
            }
        }, delayHandlerLogger);
    }
}

where logger is a public final CircularFIFOBuffer<String> logger = new CircularFIFOBuffer<>(10);:
public class CircularFIFOBuffer<T> {
    private final Object[] buffer;
    private final int maxSize;
    private int front;
    private int rear;
    private int size;

    public CircularFIFOBuffer(int maxSize) {
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
        buffer = new Object[maxSize];
        front = 0;
        rear = -1;
        size = 0;
    }

    public synchronized void enqueue(T item) {
        if (size == maxSize) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Buffer is full");
        }
        rear = (rear + 1) % maxSize;
        buffer[rear] = item;
        size++;
    }

    public synchronized T dequeue() {
        if (size == 0) {
            return null; // or throw an exception
        }
        T item = (T) buffer[front];
        front = (front + 1) % maxSize;
        size--;
        return item;
    }

    public synchronized boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    public synchronized void clear() {
        front = 0;
        rear = -1;
        size = 0;
    }

    public synchronized T peek() {
        if (size == 0) {
            return null; // or throw an exception
        }
        return (T) buffer[front];
    }
}


"when I switch Activity and check it onResume/onStart, text is empty, while within Runnable remains the appended text" - note that when you leave the activity the Runnable in processLogger continues to run every 200MS since it is self-arming. The UI element is updated in memory (despite not on screen) and would contain any updates on return to activity. Doesn't explain your observations but it may not be what you intended.

@Computable I know. But if I reset it, can't contain "old values" (different ones could be ok)

Seems a threading issue. Please check this previous SO response

public void syncSongs() {
    handlerLogger.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    loggerText.setText("");
    loggerText.post(this::processLogger);
}

public void processLogger() {
    handlerLogger.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            String loggerLine = String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt());
            String textCheck = loggerText.getText().toString();
            loggerText.append(textCheck + loggerLine + "\n");
            handlerLogger.postDelayed(this, delayHandlerLogger);
        }
    }, delayHandlerLogger);
}

I ran this code without the use of isQueueEmpty and found it was clearing the EditText everytime I called syncSongs(). Your issue lies in the isQueueEmpty method. Post the definition for that as well.
EDIT:
for(int i = 0 ; i < 30 ; i++) {
    fifo.enqueue(new Random().nextInt(100));
}

I put some values in the CircularFIFOBuffer class.
public void processLogger() {
    handlerLogger.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if(!fifo.isEmpty()) {
                String loggerLine = String.valueOf(fifo.dequeue());
                String textCheck = loggerText.getText().toString();
                loggerText.append(textCheck + loggerLine + "\n");
                handlerLogger.postDelayed(this, delayHandlerLogger);
            }
        }
    }, delayHandlerLogger);
}

I still find behavior similar to my previous attempt.

I was calling syncSongs from a Button press.

Posted the "whole" code, with the definition of logger/circular buffer and so on. Dunno its a problem with the queue, since its not related with EditText, but it could be?

Still doesnt' work on my side...

You're processing multiples runnables at same time.
try to removeCallbacks.
create a variable to store your runnable
(...)
final Handler handlerLogger = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
Runnable myRunnable;
(...)

on sync songs remove all callbacks to that runnable
public void syncSongs() {
    loggerText.setText("");
    handlerLogger.removeCallbacksAndMessages(myRunnable);
    loggerText.post(this::processLogger);
}

on process instantiate your runnable and start them
public void processLogger() {
    myRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //your logic
            handlerLogger.postDelayed(this, delayHandlerLogger);
        }
    };
    handlerLogger.postDelayed(myRunnable, delayHandlerLogger);
}


"You're processing multiples runnables at same time." why this should matter? they will access multiple time to the same object loggerText, yes, but if I clean from one "thread", it should be clean everywhere (also in a non atomic context)...

Anyway, tried your code: exactly the same problem, as I thought. loggerText text contains prev values the second time I call processLogger :(

so, when you are appending data, you're not storing previous results?

I "append", step by step, so its grown automatically. But when I reset the text, the past must gone. Instead textCheck1 and textCheck2 (which get the text from the same object at different moments) results is weird (if the first reset and its "", without append later, also the second should be "").

so, put a breakpoint in that line: String loggerLine = syncService.storageManager.logger.dequeue();
and be sure that on this line you're not storing previous data.

if possible update the question with yours SyncService and SyncServiceCallbacks

Shouldnt matter: in any case the dequeue string (i.e. loggerLine) is appended later, after reading the EditText.
